# What is my mistake when creating this grouped barplot in R and how do i resolve this?

Tags: r, dataframe, bar-chart

This is my dataframe data

> dput(data4)

```
structure(list(`number of goals scored` = c(311, 271), 
               `number of fouls commited` = c(2147, 2246)), 
               row.names = c("Hometeam", "AwayTeam"), 
               class = "data.frame")
```

This is the my barplot code and the error i get when creating the grouped barplot

```
barplot(data4, 
        main = 'total num of goals and fouls commited',
        xlab = 'Teams',ylab = 'frequency',
        col = c('red','yellow'),
        legend.text = rownames(data4),
        beside = TRUE)
```

> Error in barplot.default(data4, main = "total num of goals and fouls commited",  :    'height' must be a vector or a matrix

Comment: Wait, I think the issue is 'row.names = c("Hometeam", "AwayTeam")'. How do I actually convert it into one of the lists in under the structure instead of using the primitive way of creating it through data4$Teams = c('Hometeam", "AwayTeam')?

Comment: The issue is as the error message suggests: the first argument should be a matrix or vector, but `data4` is a data frame. How about trying `as.matrix(data4)` for the first argument to `barplot()` ? There were also some typos in your code, which I edited.

Comment: @neilfws There is an error when i tried 'as.matrix(data4)' for the first argument to barplot(). The answer provided by Hyena works.

Comment: Trust me, `as.matrix(data4)` plus the (corrected) code in your question works, I tried it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See if this is what you wanted:

```
barplot(as.matrix(data4[,1:2]), 
    main = 'total num of goals and fouls commited',
    xlab = 'Teams',ylab = 'frequency',
    col = c('red','yellow'),
    legend.text = rownames(data4),
    beside = TRUE)
```

`barplot` is asking for a matrix in the 1st argument. So give it a matrix intead of a `data.frame`.